# jquery.html() returns only first text when loaded from string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Supposedly a jquery object can be initialized from string. This can often happen when processing ajax results, i.e. I'm trying to replicate http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

However, I'm seeing strange behavior:

```
function test() {
    var content = $("<html><body><div>hello</div><div>world</div></body></html>");
    alert("content.text() = " + content.text());
    alert("content.html() = " + content.html());
}
```

The first alert shows: content.text() = helloworld

The second alert shows: content.html() = hello

What's happening here?

### Solution

Thanks everyone for the explanations. I ended up adding another layer of `<div>` to have a single child of `<body>`, as in

```
<html>
 <body>
  <div>    <=== added
   <div>hello</div>
   <div>world</div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When parsing HTML fragments containing a `body` element, browsers in general (and jQuery does this as well) will disregard everything except what's inside the `body` element. So what you have there ends up being equivalent to:

```
var content = $("<div>hello</div><div>world</div>");
alert("content.text() = " + content.text());
alert("content.html() = " + content.html());
```

You end up with a jQuery object with two elements in it: The `div` elements.

In jQuery, normally accessor functions (`html`, `val`, `css`, etc.) only use the **first** element in the set when you use them as getters, and that's what [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) is doing above. [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) is an **unusual** accessor function in jQuery: It gives you the combined text of all of the elements in the set, not just the first.

We can see this in the docs, but it's still surprising. From [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/):

> Get the HTML contents ***of the first element*** in the set of matched elements or set the HTML contents of every matched element.

From [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/):

> Get the ***combined*** text contents ***of each element*** in the set of matched elements, including their descendants, or set the text contents of the matched elements.

*(My emphasis in both cases.)*

Comment: Thanks T.J. At some point I had read all the individual parts of the documentation, but didn't put 1 +1 together.

Comment: @RudigerW.: I was really surprised by this behavior of `text`, I hadn't known about it until I saw your question and said "wait, that doesn't look right." :-) So that's a bug in my future your question helped prevent.

Answer (score 1):

Browsers remove those `html` and `body` elements. The `content` collection has only 2 `div` elements.

> When passing in complex HTML, some browsers may not generate a DOM that exactly replicates the HTML source provided. As mentioned, jQuery uses the browser's `.innerHTML` property to parse the passed HTML and insert it into the current document. During this process, some browsers filter out certain elements such as `<html>`, `<title>`, or `<head>` elements. As a result, the elements inserted may not be representative of the original string passed.

This is the string representation of your `content` collection:

```
content.map(function() { return this.outerHTML || this.nodeValue; }).get().join('');
// -> <div>hello</div><div>world</div>
```

`.text()` method returns `textContent/nodeValue` of all the elements in the collection:

```
content.text(); // -> helloworld
```

.and `.html()` method returns `innerHTML`  of *the first* element in the collection:

```
content.html(); // -> hello
```

Comment: Thanks, @Vohuman. At some point I had read all the individual parts of the documentation, but didn't put 1 +1 together. I would have accepted your answer as it was the first one and has the cool content.map solution, but T.J. Crowder's explanation was a little more thorough.

Answer (score 0):

This is what your `content` looks like to a browser:

```
"content = " Object { 0: <div>, 1: <div>, length: 2 }
```

Basically this is in some kind a set of 2 elements.

And here's what http://api.jquery.com/html/ say:

> Get the HTML contents of the first element in the set of matched elements